# NServiceBus 4 (RC1) - ReflectionTypeLoadException

Tags: nservicebus

what is the best way of troubleshooting this issue?
obviously "try… catch" in the endpointconfig (as something like below) 
can't help, because the exception occurs earlier.
this seems so basic,but I am totally stuck here(:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher, UsingTransport<Msmq>, IWantCustomInitialization
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            try
            {              
                Configure
                    .With()
                    .StructureMapBuilder(ObjectFactory.Container)
                    .NLog(new NLog.Targets.FileTarget
                    {
                        FileName = "${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log",
                        Layout = "${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}"
                    })
                    .UnicastBus();               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

* EXCEPTION*****

```
Magnum.StateMachine.StateMachineException: Exception occu
rred in Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1[[NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.Windo
wsHost, NServiceBus.Host, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc38
6479f8a226c]] during state Initial while handling OnStart ---> Microsoft.Practic
es.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Activation error occured while trying to
 get instance of type WindowsHost, key "MusicMind.Host.EndpointConfig, MusicMind
.Host, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" ---> System.Reflec
tion.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Mindestens ein Typ in der Assembly kann nicht
geladen werden. Rufen Sie die LoaderExceptions-Eigenschaft ab, wenn Sie weitere
Informationen benötigen.
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   bei System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   bei NServiceBus.Hosting.Helpers.AssemblyListExtensions.<AllTypes>d__0.MoveNex
t() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\28bfdd0d351fb1d3\src\NServiceBus.Core\Hosting
\Helpers\AssemblyListExtensions.cs:Zeile 14.
   bei System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   bei System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   bei NServiceBus.Hosting.Profiles.ProfileManager..ctor(List`1 assembliesToScan
, IConfigureThisEndpoint specifier, String[] args, List`1 defaultProfiles) in c:
\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\28bfdd0d351fb1d3\src\NServiceBus.Core\Hosting\Profiles
\ProfileManager.cs:Zeile 33.
   bei NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost..ctor(IConfigureThisEndpoint specifier, S
tring[] args, List`1 defaultProfiles, String endpointName, IEnumerable`1 scannab
leAssembliesFullName) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\28bfdd0d351fb1d3\src\NServi
ceBus.Core\Hosting\GenericHost.cs:Zeile 173.
   bei NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost..ctor(Type endpointType, String[]
 args, String endpointName, Boolean runOtherInstallers, IEnumerable`1 scannableA
ssembliesFullName) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\28bfdd0d351fb1d3\src\hosting\N
ServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\WindowsHost.cs:Zeile 29.
   bei NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.HostServiceLocator.DoGetInstance(Type service
Type, String key) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\28bfdd0d351fb1d3\src\hosting\NS
erviceBus.Hosting.Windows\HostServiceLocator.cs:Zeile 34.
   bei Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Ty
pe serviceType, String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:Zeile 49.
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Ty
pe serviceType, String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:Zeile 57.
   bei Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance[TS
ervice](String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsof
t.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:Zeile 103.
   bei Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1.BuildInstance() in c:\Projects\TopS
helfForNSB\src\Topshelf\Internal\ServiceController.cs:Zeile 93.
   bei Magnum.StateMachine.EventActionList`1.Execute(T stateMachine, Event event
, Object parameter) in :Zeile 0.
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei Magnum.StateMachine.ExceptionActionDictionary`1.HandleException(T stateMa
chine, Event event, Object parameter, Exception exception) in :Zeile 0.
   bei Magnum.StateMachine.EventActionList`1.Execute(T stateMachine, Event event
, Object parameter) in :Zeile 0.
   bei Magnum.StateMachine.State`1.RaiseEvent(T instance, BasicEvent`1 eevent, O
bject value) in :Zeile 0.
   bei Magnum.StateMachine.StateMachine`1.RaiseEvent(Event raised) in :Zeile 0.
   bei Topshelf.Internal.ServiceControllerProxy.Start()
   bei Topshelf.Internal.ServiceCoordinator.Start() in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNS
B\src\Topshelf\Internal\ServiceCoordinator.cs:Zeile 54.
   bei Topshelf.Internal.Hosts.ConsoleHost.Run() in c:\Projects\TopShelfForNSB\s
rc\Topshelf\Internal\Hosts\ConsoleHost.cs:Zeile 53.
   bei NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\TeamCity\bu
ildAgent\work\28bfdd0d351fb1d3\src\hosting\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\Program.c
s:Zeile 135.
```

**EDIT**
i found the solution!
see my last comment!

Answer (score 3):

Put a breakpoint on the Console.Writeline and examine the internal exception property in the debugger - drill in until you find the ReflectionTypeLoadException object, then examine the LoaderException property which will tell you which types couldn't be loaded.

Comment: the exception does not happen locally (win8x64) but only on production server (win2008r2x64) and i can't reproduce it in debug mode.
moreover, it's look like the exception is hapening before Init in the EndPointConfig, sothat a breakpoint wouldn't really help.
btw.
i am sure, it has nothing to do with the nservicebus but it would really help if i can somehow see which types couldn't be loaded...

Comment: **i found the solution!!!**
`NserviceBus.exe   /scannedassemblies:"NServiceBus.Host`

now i can see in the logfile which types couldn't be loaded and I can easily fix this with bindingRedirect.